# How to apply jar patch while creating war file using maven

Tags: maven, build, jar, maven-war-plugin

I have maven project that creates the war file. It includes the all the jars from dependencies.

In my case, some jar we received as a product patch. These jar should be overwrite the existing jars those added from the dependencies.

I have added the below plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>../../../product-patch/RT_V1/RT/webapps/cct-swift/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                <targetPath>/WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>../../../product-patch/Patch-4277</directory>
                <targetPath>/WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>../../../product-patch/Patch-4291</directory>
                <targetPath>/WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Finally I can see the war generated but it contains the old jar only.
I would like to achieve this task by making minimum changes in existing maven pom.xml

Comment: An optional dependency is not included. Then just bring your own.

Comment: Sorry @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, I didn't get you. Can you please explain in detail.

Thanks

Comment: You can tell Maven to exclude a dependency - https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: Or install the patch locally with a very high version number and use that version to have Maven pick the latest